# lodash json group object costs

Tags: javascript, json, underscore.js, lodash

Please,
I have this JSON object and want to group values by type.

```
var costs = [
  { 'name': 'JON', 'flight':100, 'value': 12,  type: 'uns' },
  { 'name': 'JON', 'flight':100, 'value': 35,  type: 'sch' },
  { 'name': 'BILL', 'flight':200, 'value': 33,  type: 'uns' },
  { 'name': 'BILL', 'flight':200, 'value': 45,  type: 'sch' }
];
```

I want something like this:

```
var costs = [
  { 'name': 'JON', 'flight':100, 'uns': 12,  'sch': 35 },
  { 'name': 'BILL', 'flight':200, 'uns': 33,  'sch': 45}
];
```

I try use lodash but without sucess:

```
var compiled_costs = _.chain(costs)
                      .groupBy("flight")
                      .value();

{
"100":
    [    {"name":"JON","flight":100,"value":12,"type":"uns"},
         {"name":"JON","flight":100,"value":35,"type":"sch"}
    ],
"200":
    [
         {"name":"BILL","flight":200,"value":33,"type":"uns"},  
         {"name":"BILL","flight":200,"value":45,"type":"sch"}
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var res = _.chain(costs)
    .groupBy('flight') // group costs by flight
    .mapValues(function(flightItems, flight) { // iterate flight arrays
        return { // return obj on each flight array
            name: _.get(flightItems, [0, 'name']), // just get name from first item of flight array
            flight: flight,
            uns: _.chain(flightItems) // get all flight items with type uns and sum items values
                .filter({type: 'uns'})
                .sumBy('value')
                .value(),
            sch: _.chain(flightItems)
                .filter({type: 'sch'})
                .sumBy('value')
                .value()
        }
    })
    .values() // get values from object
    .value();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use native [`reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce?v=control) method:

```js
const costs = [
  { 'name': 'JON', 'flight':100, 'value': 12,  type: 'uns' },
  { 'name': 'JON', 'flight':100, 'value': 35,  type: 'sch' },
  { 'name': 'BILL', 'flight':200, 'value': 33,  type: 'uns' },
  { 'name': 'BILL', 'flight':200, 'value': 45,  type: 'sch' }
];
const compiledCosts = costs.reduce((acc, { name, flight, value, type }) => {
  let obj = acc.find(x => x.name === name);
  if (typeof obj === 'undefined') {
    acc.push({ name, flight, [type]: value });
  } else {
    obj[type] = value;
  }
  return acc;
}, []);
console.log(compiledCosts);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a closure over a hash table for same named objects.

```js
var data = [{ name: 'JON', flight: 100, value: 12, type: 'uns' }, { name: 'JON', flight: 100, value: 35, type: 'sch' }, { name: 'BILL', flight: 200, value: 33, type: 'uns' }, { name: 'BILL', flight: 200, value: 45, type: 'sch' }],
    grouped = data.reduce(function (hash) {
        return function (r, o) {
            if (!hash[o.name]) {
                hash[o.name] = { name: o.name, flight: o.flight };
                r.push(hash[o.name]);
            }
            hash[o.name][o.type] = (hash[o.name][o.type] || 0) + o.value;
            return r;
        }
    }(Object.create(null)), []);

console.log(grouped);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: @Arildo, you are welcome. maybe you have a look here, too: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 0):

This is what Map was made for. Since you are merging the data you might want to consider keeping the hashMap for quicker lookup. Otherwise turning it into an array is trivial as I demonstrate.

```js
function compiled_costs(costs) {
  var hash = new Map();
  for (let cost of costs) {
    if (hash.has(cost.name)) {
      var values = hash.get(cost.name),
        value = values.value,
        type = values.type;
      delete values.value;
      delete values.type;
      values.uns = value;
      values.sch = cost.value;
    } else hash.set(cost.name, cost)
  }
  return hash
}

var costs = [{
    'name': 'JON',
    'flight': 100,
    'value': 12,
    type: 'uns'
  },
  {
    'name': 'JON',
    'flight': 100,
    'value': 35,
    type: 'sch'
  },
  {
    'name': 'BILL',
    'flight': 200,
    'value': 33,
    type: 'uns'
  },
  {
    'name': 'BILL',
    'flight': 200,
    'value': 45,
    type: 'sch'
  }
];

var formated = [...compiled_costs(costs).values()];
//formated
console.log('formated',formated);
//hashed
var hashed = [...compiled_costs(costs)];
console.log('hashed',hashed);
```